# Como utilizar o xmlSApply com separador?

Tags: xml, r, apply

Utilizei o `xmlSApply` e gostaria de obter o resultado com um separador mas não soube aplicar.

Abaixo segue um exemplo para que possam reproduzir:

```
library(XML)
fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileUrl,useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
xmlName(rootNode)
names(rootNode)
```

O conteúdo do primeiro nó:

```
rootNode[[1]]
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
```

E o resultado de `xmlSApply(rootNode, xmlValue)` :

```
food
"Belgian Waffles$5.95Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup650"
food 
"Strawberry Belgian Waffles$7.95Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream900"
food
"Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles$8.95Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream900" 
food
"French Toast$4.50Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread600" 
food
"Homestyle Breakfast$6.95Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns950"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma seria:

```
nos <- lapply(xmlChildren(rootNode), function(x) xmlApply(x, xmlValue))
nos[[1]]
$name
[1] "Belgian Waffles"

$price
[1] "$5.95"

$description
[1] "Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup"

$calories
[1] "650"
```

Isto te dá uma lista para cada `food` com os subelementos separados `name`, `price`, `description` e `calories`. E se por "separador" você quer dizer colar os valores separados, você poderia fazer em seguida:

```
textos <- sapply(nos, function(x) paste(x, collapse=" "))
textos[[1]]
[1] "Belgian Waffles $5.95 Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup 650"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Carlos! Era o que eu precisava.